# Is it possible to create different custom messages for Wordpress password protected pages?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website with 2 different pages that are protected using the native Wordpress password protect functionality.

I am looking for a way (if one exists) to customize the text above the password field differently for different password-protected pages.

I found a plugin that replaces the default text with custom HTML code, but then this message displays for ALL password protected pages.

What I'm trying to achieve is for password-protected page A to show "Message A" above the password field, and password-protected page B to show "Message B" above the password field, whereas currently all password-protected pages display the same message.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Someone should provide this functionality via a plugin... aaaand, go!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

Yo have to add this code to your ***functions.php*** :

```
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'custom_password_protected_form' );

function custom_password_protected_form($output) {
    global $post;

    switch ($post->post_name) {
        case 'page-a':
            $replacement_text = 'Message A';
            break;
        case 'page-b':
            $replacement_text = 'Message B';
        case 'default':
            $replacement_text = '';
    }

    if (!empty($replacement_text)) $output = str_replace(__( 'This content is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:' ), $replacement_text, $output);
    return $output;
}
```

Tested on WP 5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Hook into `the_password_form` filter and write your own custom password form as a variation of the default one. Then you can add any custom logic you want like detecting the page and outputting a different message.

In my example I am using `is_page()` to determine the page but you could use any logic here you want.

```
function my_custom_password_form() {
  global $post;

  // custom logic for the message
  $password_form_message = is_page('Private Page One') ?
    __( "MESSAGE FOR ONE PAGE... This post is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:" ) :
    __( "MESSAGE FOR ANOTHER PAGE... This post is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:" );

  // put together the custom form using the dynamic message
  $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
  $form = '<form class="protected-post-form" action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-pass.php" method="post">
  ' . $password_form_message . '
  <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
  </form>
  ';
  return $form;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_custom_password_form' );
```